# Appropriate use of HTML's VAR tag

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have a webpage that combines static and dynamic content. The dynamic content comes from user input supplied on another webpage. The dynamic content must be visually different (italics, underlined, different font, etc. -- using CSS, of course) from the static content, as in:

> I reside in *Athens*.

Is it semantically appropriate to use the `VAR` tag around the dynamic content? For example:

```
I reside in <var>Athens</var>.
```

The documentation on the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/var.html) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/var) sites seems to indicate that this may be misusing `VAR`.

If `VAR` is not appropriate, is there another suitable tag, or should I just use `SPAN`?

Comment: `<var>` is for math/code, so how would that be appropriate?

Comment: "Is it semantically appropriate to use the `VAR` tag around the dynamic content?" No.

Comment: Use the `span` tag with an appropriate class.

Comment: @j08691: Not it's not math, but it isn't evident to me that it isn't code. From a programmer's perspective, "Athens" seems like the value of a variable -- hence my confusion with VAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`var` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/text-level-semantics.html#the-var-element) is not appropriate.

It doesn’t matter how your content is produced technically; it only matters what it represents. While there are cases where `var` can be used in contexts other than formulas/code ("a placeholder in prose"), your example doesn’t seem to be one of those.

For deciding which element to use instead, it is important to know the specific case. Good questions to ask:

- *Why exactly do I want to highlight the dynamic content?*
- *What am I trying to convey by this?*

As the specific case is not known, there are only two possible candidates:

- [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element): doesn’t change the meaning, doesn’t mean anything.
- [`b`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element): doesn’t change the meaning, only draws attention to the content (but doesn’t make it more important by that).

About elements others suggested as alternative:

- [`em`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element): Only to be used for "stress emphasis". For example, when someone says that she resides in Bern, she could answer: `I reside in <em>Athens</em>.` Don’t use this in the general case.
- [`ìns`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/edits.html#the-ins-element): Only to be used when the content was added to the document; again, the technical side doesn’t matter (every content gets added *somehow*, right?), it only matters what it represents. Examples: corrections, "[sic]" in quotes, new incidents in a newspaper article, etc.
- [`kbd`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/text-level-semantics.html#the-kbd-element): Only to be used when content is to be input by the user somehow (something to type into a search field, something to click on in a software etc.); it doesn’t matter how the content managed to find its way into the document (the whole document was user input at some point!), but what it represents *now*. As "Athens" is not something the reader should input anywhere, `kbd` is not appropriate.

Comment: You make many good points. Well done (and a +1)! What are your thoughts on the KBR (I think he meant KBD) tag that SVSchmidt suggested?

Comment: @Theophilus: Ah, missed that one. Added an entry about `kbd` to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your wise counsel. Regrettably, it seems that HTML 5 does not have a semantically suitable tag for my purposes, so I will fall back to SPAN with a class for styling.

Comment: I do not understand why do we actually need var tag in html? @unor

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [<em> tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_em.asp) for "emphasized text", or use the [<span> tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) with CSS styling to indicate that the "Athens" text is different.

If you are not trying to stylize the "Athens" text in any way, you may consider that there is no need to wrap the text with any special HTML tags.

In order to stylize the data you wrap with the <em> tag, you may use something like the following:

```
<style>
    .input-received em {
        font-style: italics;
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>

<p class="input-received">I reside in <em>Athens</em>.</p>
```

Comment: Yes, "Athens" must be stylized.

Comment: I've updated my response to show how you can stylize "Athens" in the resulting HTML/CSS that you would be responsible for generating.

Comment: The EM tag won't work for my purposes because it's used elsewhere on the webpage for static text needing emphasis. Therefore, am I correct to assume that you recommend SPAN above any other HTML tag? (By the way, I don't need help with the CSS. The intent of the question is about choosing the appropriate HTML tag.)

Comment: The purpose of the <em> tag is to show emphasis, so if you are showing emphasis, then this is the right tag for you. Using an <em> tag elsewhere should not deter you from using it here.

Comment: I don't think EM is appropriate for my situation because the dynamic content does not need to be emphasized. It does, however, need to look different from the static content.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `<var>` is for variables, for example in mathematical operations. So using it this way would be semantically wrong.

You could use the `<ins>` tag (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ins.html#ins)

> The ins element represents a range of text that has been inserted (added) to a document.

I believe the question which tag should be preferred is difficult. Referring to the specification you may also use `<kbr>` (keyboard input). It's a question of interpretation sometimes I think

If unsure, just use a general tag, in this case a span with an appropriate class. Or ignore semantics and use the tag you think is best.

Comment: @SVSchmindt: I believe you understand the intent of my question. I am going to ponder your INS and KBR (Did you actually mean KBD?) suggestions before marking this as the answer. Meanwhile, do you have any thoughts regarding my reply to j08691 under the main question that may change your thoughts concerning VAR? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I meant KBR. I mistyped it.

As I mentioned before, I believe finding the right tag for making your HTML more logical, is difficult and a question of interpretation.
The specification states that VAR is meant for variables, not for variables' values. An actual example is `<var>x</var> = <var>y</var> + 2`.

After rethinking your question, I would use INS or OUTPUT (HTML 5), which represents "the result of a calculation or USER ACTION" (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output).

Comment: I'm confused. You typed KBR again in your last comment and I cannot find anything about a KBR tag on the Internet. Did you mean KBD? Regardless, I gave a +1 to your answer because it is thoughtful and helpful!

Comment: Uh, kbD. Sorry for that!

Comment: You and others have convinced me that VAR is not appropriate for my purposes. I have read W3C's and MDN's information on INS and KBD and don't feel like they are appropriate for me either. It looks like I will use SPAN with a class. Thank you for your valued input!